# Weighted average reverse

Tags: excel, average, weighted

I am calculating weighted average based on BENEFITS (60%) and EFFORTS (40%) and give a total score.

Example table:

**CRITERIA |    WEIGHTAGE | SCORE**

BENEFITS | 60% |  10

EFFORTS |   40% | 1

TOTAL
SCORE | 100% |  **6.4**

**For EFFORTS I want weighted calculation to be reversed, so, lower number should show increased TOTAL SCORE.**

= -(40% * 1) -- do you think adding -ve to the calculation will give to correct score or is there any better formula in excel please?

[LINK TO EXAMPLE FILE](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13Vgydzy0QbCGkMSC4X5Z20GvI4kgVOeoJSzMaVtEKpk/edit?usp=sharing)

Thanks

Comment: So efforts should be 60% and benefits 40%? Then yes (1 - criteria) will do the trick.

Comment: No.  I want to keep the same weightage factors but if a user enter 1 for EFFORTS then TOTAL SCORE should increase and 10 should decrease the TOTAL.

Comment: I think you should give some more examples.

Comment: I have added a link to the google sheet if that helps

Answer (score 0):

Managed to solve this by substracting 10(max scoring number a user can enter) to existing score.  This will reverse the scoring affect on the calculations.